# Basic dockerfile with php and apache won't mount

Tags: php, docker, apache, dockerfile

I want a plain PHP app (apache with php)to run in a docker container, also a volume from my local filesystem to the container's.

I have a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.3-apache

COPY . /var/www/html

EXPOSE 80/tcp
```

after building this image with `$ docker build -t <some-name-for-my-image> .` and running it with `docker container run -dp 80:80 -v "$(pwd):/var/www/html/" <some-name-for-my-image>` it works but the volumes don't work, If modify something locally It won't update automatically in the container, any ideas what am I missing?

Comment: can you try instead of `COPY` use `ADD` and make sure you build and run container from the same path the Dockerfile is in, if it does not work ill try full path name.

Comment: I tried it now but unfortunately it won't mount upon saving

Comment: Did you try full path name ? instead of `.`

Comment: So I have a project folder under my C:/ trying ```COPY C:/my-project-folder /var/www/html``` gives me errors although running ```docker run -d -p 80:80  -v C:/my-folder:/var/www/html/ myimage``` works, thank you